# Unable to filter rows in a data frame conditionally by two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I am trying to filter some rows in the data frame if the value of COLUMN 'A' in the data frame is over a value and only if the row have more than X value in COLUMN 'B'.

This is the code I've tried:

```py
df11['media_precio'] = df11.groupby(['Amueblado','Habitaciones','Tipo Planta','Ascensor'])['Precio_Mercado'].transform('mean')

df11['Numero_x'] = df11.groupby(['Amueblado','Habitaciones','Tipo Planta','Ascensor'])['Link-href'].transform('count')

df12 = df11[df11.apply(lambda x: (x['Precio'] <= x['media_precio'] * 1.1) if x['Numero_x'] > 5 else x, axis=1)]
```

The error that is appearing is

> ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the error on `if x['Numero_x'] > 5 else x`? Would be helpful to have a sample dataframe to refer to.

Comment: You mention column A and B but your last line uses 3 different columns including on not in earlier two assignments: `Precio`. Please explain in words what condition you want to subset rows. The ternary operator in `lambda` is not clear as `else x` does not return booleans.

Comment: Yes @LifeisGood the error appears when I add the "if x['Numero_x'] > 5 else x".

There are 3 columns in play @Parfait.
1. ['Precio`]-> type float it has prices in it.
2. ['media_precio']-> it has the mean of the prices per group
3. ['Numero_x']-> it has the number of rows/elements per group (same group of the previous column)

What I want to do is to filter the rows which Price is above 1.1*mean price of its group only when this group has more than 5 rows/elements.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Column['Precio']= type int, it has prices

Comment: In that case, I would go for something like `df12 = df11.loc[(x['Precio'] <= x['media_precio'] * 1.1) & (x['Numero_x'] > 5)]`

Comment: @LifeisGood that's not working because it is filtering all the rows which column "Numero_x" is less than 5 which is not why want to do.
What I want to do is to apply the filter "x['Precio'] <= x['media_precio']" only if "x['Numero_x'] > 5) = True".

Comment: So you would prefer one condition to be satisfied before the other condition. Say that we have 4 elements in a group, then using the "if", we don't evaluate the `x['Precio'] <= x['media_precio']` anymore. Is your intention to be more computationally efficient?